# Find all combinations of 1 and 2 that add up to N

Tags: c#, algorithm

Say I have a function like this.  I need to know all the combinations of 1 and 2 that will add up to N.  Is there a better way to write this that would perform better for a large integer such as N = 1200 or 12000?

```
public static int Combos(int n)
{
    if (n < 3)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return Combos(n - 1) + Combos(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider the following: how many times does the `Combos` method get called when you run this recursively?  Does this algorithm calculate things more than once?  (Spoiler alert: it does.)

Comment: you are not finding any combination in this method. it just returns a number, im not sure what that number means. am i missing something?

Comment: Your algorithm that you have implemented will return the number of permutations, not combinations, of 1s and 2s that add up to N. For example if you pass in Combos(3) you will get an answer of 3 (1, 1, 1), (1, 2), and (2, 1). Did you want it to treat (1, 2) and (2, 1) as different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of permutations optimized:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var result = Combos(1200);
}

static Dictionary<long, long> cache = new Dictionary<long, long>();
public static long Combos(long n)
{           
   if (n < 3)
   {
      return n;
   }
   else
   {
      if (!cache.TryGetValue(n - 1, out long combos1))
      {
          combos1 = Combos(n - 1);
          cache.Add(n - 1, combos1);
      }
      if (!cache.TryGetValue(n - 2, out long combos2))
      {
          combos2 = Combos(n - 2);
          cache.Add(n - 2, combos2);
      }
      return combos1 + combos2;
   }
}
```

If you need combinations then you need to ask separate question to optimize the following code (from the following [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-combinations-that-adds-upto-given-number-2/)):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FindCombinations(20);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        //IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>
        static void FindCombinationsUtil(int[] arr, int index,
                                 int num, int reducedNum)
        {
            // Base condition 
            if (reducedNum < 0)
                return;

            // If combination is  
            // found, print it 
            if (reducedNum == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                    Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
                return;
                //yield return arr;                                
            }

            // Find the previous number  
            // stored in arr[]. It helps  
            // in maintaining increasing  
            // order 
            int prev = (index == 0) ?
                                  1 : arr[index - 1];

            // note loop starts from  
            // previous number i.e. at 
            // array location index - 1 
            for (int k = prev; k <= num; k++)
            {
                // next element of 
                // array is k 
                arr[index] = k;

                // call recursively with 
                // reduced number 
                FindCombinationsUtil(arr, index + 1, num,
                                         reducedNum - k);
            }
        }

        /* Function to find out all  
        combinations of positive  
        numbers that add upto given 
        number. It uses findCombinationsUtil() */
        static void FindCombinations(int n)
        {
            // array to store the combinations 
            // It can contain max n elements 
            int[] array = new int[n];

            // find all combinations 
            FindCombinationsUtil(array, 0, 2, n);            
        }
```

Comment: Does this not answer 'how many combinations', and not what are the combinations? `Combos(2)` yields 2. The OP needs to know "all the combinations", so ideally he should get `IEnumerable`s in sequence, one representing each combination, In the 2 case, a `1 1` and a `2`.

Comment: @schulmaster The method in the question returns an `int`, and despite some ambiguity in the wording, I'd say no, the OP is just looking for a better way of finding how many.

Comment: @AccessDenied - this looks like it will work.  Far faster than the original.  I actually needed permutations, rather than combinations.  I didn't realize this is such an active area of discussion.

Comment: @AccessDenied - Is using the HashSet what leads to better performance?

Comment: @AccessDenied, meant to say Dictionary rather than HashSet.  I had thought of using a HashSet and then comparing the original list with the HashSet

Comment: You can use two arrays: bool and int it will work even faster than dictionary. Bool to check if value was calculated, int to store value. Yes, the dictionary what makes it faster, this approach comes from dynamic programming.

Answer (score 5):

> Find all combinations of 1 and 2 that add up to N

So, you need `combinations` and **not permutations**.

Let's see some examples-

- 1 = {1}
- 2 = {1,1}, {2}
- 3 = {1,1,1}, {1,2} (or {2,1} , both are same).
- 4 = {1,1,1,1}, {1,2,1}, {2,2}
- 5 = {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,1,1}, {2,2,1}
- 6 = {1,1,1,1,1,1}, { 1,2,1,1,1} , {2,2,1,1} , {2,2,2}
- 7 = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, { 1,2,1,1,1,1} , {2,2,1,1,1} , {2,2,2,1}

If you observe, it looks like this-

- 1 = 1
- 2 = 2
- 3 = 2
- 4 = 3
- 5 = 3
- 6 = 4
- 7 = 4
- 8 = 5

You can solve this in `O(1)` time and `O(1)` space like below-

```
public static int Combos(int n){
    return n / 2 + 1;
}
```

**Note #1:** If you need values also, then it will take a bit more effort, but with your code it looks like you only want to find no. of ways.

**Note #2:** Finding the actual values would also not take much effort if you notice. You don't need to remember previous results at all.

Comment: Simple: First combination is all 1's, then for each subsequent combination, as long as there are 2 or more 1's left, grab the first two 1's, replace them with a single 2, that's your next combination, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Not actually, as your case 4 = {1,1,1,1}, {1,2,1}, {2,2} is also valid with 4 = {1,1,1,1}, {2,1,1},{1,1,2}, {2,2}

Comment: @bitshift {1,2,1} , {2,1,1} , { 1,1,2} are all the same when it comes to combinations.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in your sample calculates the number of permutations, not combinations, of 1's and 2's that add up to a number N, so I'll answer a way to find the answer to that faster.

Firstly, let's try running it for the first few numbers

```
> Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(Combos).ToList()
List<int>(20) { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946 }
```

This sequence is actually a well known sequence, it's the sequence of fibonacci numbers!

The code that you posted is the typical example of the naive recursive implementation of calculating fibonacci numbers, and is an example that is often used when teaching about dynamic programming.

There are many resources online about how to implement a faster approach, but one such way is to build the value from the bottom up rather than the top down such as the following:

```
int Combos(int n)
{
    if (n < 3)
        return n;
    int previous = 2;
    int previous2 = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int newValue = previous + previous2;
        previous2 = previous;
        previous = newValue;
    }
    return previous;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.